# jQuery validating input type number

Tags: jquery, input, numbers

I'm trying to set function onFocusOut event with jQuery like:

```
$(':number').keypress(function (evt){
    //validating cone
}
```

but it can't select number types throwing an error

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: number

Same code for type text works fine.

Does jQuery not know a number datatype? How to make it work?

Comment: There is no such thing as `:number`, as it says

Comment: True, but `:text` is for `input type="text"` so i think it should be same thing for other types. Is that because `number` type is from HTML5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to select `<input>` elements with the `number` as the `type`? Try this:

```
$('input[type="number"]').keypress(function (evt){

}
```

Comment: or `$('input[type="number"]')` which is faster.

Comment: It works, thanks. Was trying before something like `$('input[type="number"]')` with i found on internet bud didnt work .(possible i've made an error in syntax then...) Btw laso found examples with `$('input.number]')`, but it doesnt work also...

Comment: @T.G, `input.number` is for selecting `<input/>` elements with class `number`. Completely unrelated for what you wanted to do. You better try to understand selectors instead of just *googling*

Comment: one more thing. Chrome and some other browsers do validation of numeric fields as well... how to disable it? I tied `$('input[type="number"]').unbind('blur');` etc, but with no effect

Answer (score 1):

For the record, you can extend jQuery to add a custom `:number` selector.

```
$.expr[':']​​​​.number = function(elem){
  return $(elem).is("input[type='number']");
}​;
```

Or pure javascript.

```
$.expr[':']​​​​.number = function(elem){
  return (elem.tagName === "INPUT") &&
         elem.getAttribute("type") &&
         (elem.getAttribute("type").toUpperCase() === "NUMBER");
}​;
```